# Can Open Telemetry Instrument Two Express Services in the Same Node Program?

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry

Let's say I have a NodeJS program that has *two* separate instances of an express server running.

```
const express = require('express')
const app1 = express()
app1.listen(3000, () => { //... })

//...

const app2 = express()
app2.listen(3001, () => { //... })
```

I've been able to instrument a program like this via [open telemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/), and have my spans sent/exported successfully to Zipkin. All I needed to do is/was add code like the following to the start of my program.

```
  const { NodeTracerProvider } = require('@opentelemetry/node');
  const { ZipkinExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin');

  const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    plugins: {
      express: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      http: {
        requestHook: (span, request) => {
          span.setAttribute("custom request hook attribute", "request");
        },
      },
    }
  });

  const options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans',
    serviceName: 'service-main'
  }
  const zipkinExporter = new ZipkinExporter(options);
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(zipkinExporter))

  provider.register();
```

and make sure that the express and http plugins were/are installed

```
npm install @opentelemetry/plugin-http @opentelemetry/plugin-express
```

This all works great -- except for *one thing*.  Open Telemetry sees both my express services running as the same `service-main` service.

When I instrumented these services **directly** with Zipkin -- I would add the Zipkin middleware to each running express server

```
app1.use(zipkinMiddleware({tracer: tracer1}));      

app2.use(zipkinMiddleware({tracer: tracer2}));
```

Each tracer could be instantiated with its own service name, which allowed each service to have its individual name and show up as a different service in Zipkin.

[image]
(`/main`, `/hello`, and `/goobye` are all service via a different express service in the above URL)

Is this sort of thing (instrumenting two services in one program) possible with Open Telemetry?  Or would I need to separate these two services out into separate programs in order to have each services have an individual name?  This question is less about solving a particular problem, and more about understanding the semantics of Open Telemetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create two separate tracer providers. Only one of them will be the global tracer provider, which the API will use if you call API methods. You can't use the plugins in this configuration, which means you will have to manually instrument your application. If this is a use-case which is important to you, I suggest you create an issue on the github repo.

Comment: thank you!  FWIW -- this use case is _not_ particularly important to me, it just came about as a compared/contrasted with Zipkin, and this answer  helped clarify the role of trace provider vs. plugins for me.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can have multiple express running in the same node process (thats how clustering works in node as well)

but you will need to have them running on different ports.;

```
# const express = require('express')
const app1 = express()
app1.listen(3001, () => { //... })

//...

const app2 = express()
app2.listen(3002, () => { //... })
```

Comment: thank you!  FWIW -- this use case is _not_ particularly important to me, it just came about as I compared/contrasted with Zipkin, and this answer  helped clarify the role of trace provider vs. plugins for me.